# Building an application with clang with --coverage on windows

Tags: windows, cmake, clang, code-coverage

i'm trying to build a simple cmake application to test the coverage functionality offer by clang in windows (in linux all work ok).

Environment is:
Clang version in use: 7.0
And using LLVM toolset with Visual Studio 2017 build tools
cmake 3.12 with ninja generator

What I'm doing is simple:
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2 FATAL_ERROR)

project(test)

add_compile_options(--coverage)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    main.cpp
)
```

the main.cpp is as simple as it can get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "\ndone.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

using the build tools environments vcvarsall.bat i initialize the environement to run and compile with clang, like that:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_LINKER=lld-link ..
cmake --build .
```

and the following errors hapear:

```
lld-link.exe: error: undefined symbol: __llvm_profile_runtime
>>> referenced by src\app\CMakeFiles\app.dir\main.cpp.obj:(__llvm_profile_runtime_user)


lld-link.exe: error: undefined symbol: __llvm_profile_register_function
>>> referenced by src\app\CMakeFiles\app.dir\main.cpp.obj:(__llvm_profile_register_functions)
>>> referenced by src\app\CMakeFiles\app.dir\main.cpp.obj:(__llvm_profile_register_functions)
```

What i'm doing wrong or what i need to link to?

Thanks

**Update:** with Fred input I realized what library I should be linking to, and if I add the following:

```
link_libraries("C:/Program Files/LLVM/lib/clang/7.0.0/lib/windows/clang_rt.profile-x86_64.lib")
```

everything works... but is this really the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to these [Notes](https://llvm.org/docs/CoverageMappingFormat.html#quick-start) and [Notes](http://logan.tw/posts/2015/04/28/check-code-coverage-with-clang-and-lcov/) and simple [example](https://marco-c.github.io/2018/01/09/code-coverage-with-clang-on-windows.html) and another [example](https://alastairs-place.net/blog/2016/05/20/code-coverage-from-the-command-line-with-clang/) you need to do this differently.

```
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping)
```

I haven't tested the syntax or anything.
From what I gather is that `--coverage` is an older flag of making `gcov` compatible data.  The LLVM documents give an example of `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping` at compile and link command there is no documentation of `--coverage`.  One of the examples say you need to link with `--coverage` the other example says you need to link with `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping` and it will link in the profile libraries as needed.

Comment: yes indeed i also think that, but what happens is that the linker does not recognise the --coverage flag, is says "lld-link.exe: warning: ignoring unknown argument: --coverage"... it seems that there are issues with clang in windows because in linux it works fine.

Comment: Update with a second example of how it should work on the command line. This example says it links with `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping`.  I don't have the tools so I was just basing it on the examples.  At the command line you might want to run `lld-link.exe --help` and see what the options are?

Comment: thanks Fred for the help, but the problem is in the linking phase and the linker does not know any of these flags (help also does not reference any of the above flags), what seems is that in windows i'm missing a library to link to...

Comment: Using LLVM 6.0.0 on Windows 7 works on the command line like the examples.  `--coverage` produces `gcov` style coverage when using `clang++` or `clang-cl`.  `clang-cl -fprofile-instr-generate` produces a LLVM profile output.  Neither had issues linking.  It's probably something to do with your setup.

Comment: yes like you are saying there are no problems, but using cmake the problems reported happear... don't know why..

Comment: I was finally able to reproduce the issue.  When using `lld-link` ignores the `"C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\6.0.0\\lib\\windows\\clang_rt.profile-x86_64.lib"` library on the link line.  If you run `clang++` on the command line in a Visual Studio Development shell it uses `LINK.exe` and everything works. If you use `LLVM` toolset with the Visual Studio it uses `lld-link.exe` and ignores the library.  I assumed you were using a different generator.  Perhaps if you updated the question with details on the tools / versions / generator being used someone more knowledgeable can help.

Comment: you are completely right... adding that library to the target link libraries list it works... seems to me that there is a problem on clang side for windows for sure.
I will update the question with your sugestion, thanks Fred